# Display two decimal values for only one field and no decimals for the rest of the fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a column of float type. Currently I need to display two decimal places when MeasureDesc = 'Amount' for all others I can have whole numbers.

Any ideas?

```
 SELECT 
 //This works correctly. It shows decimal only when MeasureDesc = 'Amount'
 CASE WHEN tbl_Measures.MeasureDesc = 'Amount' THEN   CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), MeasureCount)
 //Here I wanted it to show no decimals when it does MeasureDesc not equal 'Amount'
 WHEN tbl_Measures.MeasureDesc != 'Amount' THEN //Show no decimals

 END as MeasureCount, tbl_Measures.Name

 FROM tblData
```

I tried using FLOOR(MeasureCount) but it drops all decimals in the column.

Comment: You can't mix datatypes in a single column. There is no work around for this.

Answer (score 0):

Display of decimal places should really be handled by your UI, whatever that is. Ultimately you need to display your values as strings to get this to work.

Assuming your UI is SQL Management Studio (;-)), this should do the trick:

```
SELECT MeasureDesc,
    CASE WHEN MeasureDesc = 'Amount' THEN Convert(varchar, Convert(decimal(10,2), MeasureCount))
    ELSE Convert(varchar, convert(int, MeasureCount)) END
FROM #tblData
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae995/1

Comment: Agreed that this should be done in the front end. However, if you are going to use varchar you always need to specify the length or it will use the default. And to make things more exciting, the default length can change depending on how it is used. >.<

Comment: Good point, I was not concerning myself with lengths for this example.  The default length when using CAST or CONVERT is 30. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx